# android Application class onLowMemory

Tags: android, android-applicationinfo

i have an application which saves some objects in my Application class for global use.
i don't want the Application class to be killed (because i need the information which is saved in it), so i've override the `onLowMemory()` function to make a `Thread.sleep(1000)`

what will happen when the Application class will awake if the memory is still low ? will call the onLowMemory() again ?

what is the right architecture to make sure this Application class won't be killed by system as long as my application and it's background services are running ?

Comment: By definition, your Application instance "won't be killed by system as long as my application and it's background services are running". The Application object lives for the lifetime of the process. However, Android can terminate your process at any time, for any reason, which will get rid of your background services and your Application instance.

Comment: i have a STICKY background Service which uses the Application. how can i determine if the Application has been reloaded when the background was reloaded or is it the original Application ?

Comment: to be more accurate - how can i know if my background Service has been killed and recreate in order to re-initialize variable in my Application object ?

Comment: If the variable is `null`, initialize it.

Comment: you mean a variable inside the Application object ?

Comment: Whatever variable you were referring to in the phrase "in order to re-initialize variable in my Application object".

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that !

1. don't block system calls
2. that doesn't prevent the system from killing your app
3. the memory will still be low

There is no way to make sure your app doesn't get killed. save your data in a sharedpreference, a file, or a sqlite db, whichever suits your needs, but don't rely on the application instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not trust that function on being called. Android can kill your application whenever it wants, as long as it is in the background, and you can't really stop him or even attempt. It may call that function so your application can clear some caches or do anything it can do to free up some memory. That can be concluded from the documentation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory()

Try to avoid relying on it. Do whatever you can to prepare your application for switching on `OnPause`, `OnStop` or `onDestroy` or similar methods that are sure to be called. That means saving variables, data or anything else that is important to a file or a database.